# HR wants to terminate a member of my team

Tags: termination

I am managing a team internationally. one of my team members in another country has access to attendance DB and he changed his attendance from DB directly to be meeting the time attendance policy of the company.
HR in his country discovered this and wants to terminate him. he is the only technical guy in this office and he is hard-worker, and saving a lot of my efforts to handle some technical issues related to this country. and finding a replacement is not an easy process due to high level of customization of our product.
Do you think that i should approve the HR decision or stand against it.
I know this is a very specific question, but i need an advice only (if you were me, what would you do)

Comment: "What should I do?" questions aren't really a good fit for Workplace.SE, as there are too many options and it's entirely opinion based.

Comment: The way this question is worded, makes it very specific to your situation and it seems like you are seeking the advice of a mentor more than a technical solution. Having that said, I see two valuable issues here which can be discussed: How do I reprimand the unethical behavior of one of my subordinates?  / How can I defend my subordinates from dismissal, when I believe she/he deserves a second chance?

Comment: _he changed his attendance from DB directly_ I would fire him immediately if I were you because I know if I don't, he probably would steal money from the company's account next time.

Comment: I would first find out why he changed his attendance - perhaps it was for a personal reasons. Anyway - how was he able to do this in the first place? Was this a once off?

Comment: If I were in your position, I would figure out how to fix the broken system which lets an employee edit his attendance record. Alternatively, I would question the broken policy which makes a big deal out of how much time the employee's bum is in contact with the office chair, especially since he is getting important work done despite the shortfall in attendance. Probably not the answer you were looking for, but you did ask what I would do in the situation.

Comment: Timecard fraud is a serious legal issue. You can lose contracts/ clients over this sort of thing. Further, anyone with access to production systems who is wiling to change things in the backend on one has the possibility of changing this or committing financial fraud or stealing personal information. If he can't be trusted with the time card application, he cannot be trusted to access any other system your company has. This is a big deal with people who have production access. This is NOT a person we want in our profession or working for your company no matter how good his technical work is.

Comment: In my opinion, his motive was to get paid for that day he didn't work. You don't want to lose him because he's beneficial to you, but definitely not to the company. How can you explain such an act in wanting to keep a co-worker and not be looked upon as if you can do the same thing in their eyes

Comment: You can always inform HR of any facts you think they would need to consider, for example if they want to fire (and have excellent reason to fire) an employee, and you know that he is currently indispensable, then they should know about that. It's then up to them how to handle this.